# SysDateTime() on Insert Query as parameter

Tags: c#, sql

This is the scenario:

I need to insert some rows on my database, one of the columns is DateTime type, which has SysDateTime as Value, usually my query looks like this

```
String sqlString = "INSERT INTO Temas(Id, Level,Date, Description) " + 
                        " VALUES (100, 3, SYSDATETIME() , 'Text ')";
```

Now i have to make the insert using parameters, now it looks like this:

```
private void InsertTemaInTesauro(OleDbDataReader origenReader,Materias materia)
    {
        SqlConnection connectionEpsOle = Conexiones.GetConecction();
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataRow dr;

            string sqlCadena = "SELECT * FROM Temas WHERE idTema = 0";
            dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            dataAdapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlCadena, connectionEpsOle);

            dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet, "Temas");

            dr = dataSet.Tables["Temas"].NewRow();
            dr["Id"] = 100;
            dr["Level"] = 3;
            dr["Date"] = ????;
            dr["Description"] = 'Some text';

            dataSet.Tables["Temas"].Rows.Add(dr);

            //dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = connectionEpsOle.CreateCommand();
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand = connectionEpsOle.CreateCommand();
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText =
                                                   "INSERT INTO Temas(Id,Level,Date,Description) (@Id,@Level,@Date,@Description)";

            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Numeric, 0, "Id");
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Level", SqlDbType.Numeric, 0, "Level");
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 0, "Date");
            dataAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Description", SqlDbType.Numeric, 0, "Description");

            dataAdapter.Update(dataSet, "Temas");

            dataSet.Dispose();
            dataAdapter.Dispose();
            connectionEpsOle.Close();
    }
```

My question is how to set the parameter of date to take the value of sysdatetime(), i can´t set it as the default value of the column because i have no access to the database and i can´t use DateTime.Now because the boss wants the time of the database

Comment: How about running a query beforehand to get the SysDateTime?

Comment: The objective of your question doesn't make much sense.  Parameters are for passing values from your code to the query. If you want to use the value of `SYSDATETIME()` in your query, then just use `SYSDATETIME()` in your query and use parameters for everything else. Why jump through hoops to find a less effective solution than you already have?

Comment: Why not just use: `DateTime.Now` for the parameter if you want to provide date/time from client. If you want to use server time don't use a parameter there.. Use `SYSDATETIME()` instead, as you've been doing before. That's perfectly valid.

Comment: In your situation, to use a parameterised query, you may have to run another query like `select sysdatetime()` to get the DateTime from database server and then assign it to the `@Date` parameter.

Comment: @JLRishe you're right as Garret Vlieger, sometimes we look for a solution we already have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can simply do this:

```
dataAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = 
   "INSERT INTO Temas(Id,Level,Date,Description) (@Id,@Level,SYSDATETIME(),@Description)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you just do

dataAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Temas(Id,Level,Date,Description) (@Id,@Level, SYSDATETIME() ,@Description)";

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I am on my phone right now so this might not be the exact answer but you will get it -

```
dataAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Temas(Id,Level,Date, Description) (@Id,@Level, SYSDATETIME(), @Description")";
```